# Watchkit Fall detection api

Tags: watchkit, watchos

we have implemented the fall detection api using **CMFallDetectionManager** in watch app, does any one idea how to simulate this test?

Answer (score 1):

When you run your app on the watchOS simulator on the Mac you can use the **Features** menu to **Simulate Fall** and then choose the type of fall dectection you want to test your code with?

[image]